# Pandas is refusing to parse a specific Wikipedia page

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I'm trying to work with some data on presidential elections in the US, so I'm using pandas to parse Wikipedia pages containing the results. For some reason, the page for the 2012 election is parsed alright, while trying to parse the page for the 2016 one results in an extremely curious error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_2012 = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_United_States_presidential_election")
>>> df_2016 = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    df_2016 = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election")
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1205, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1009, in _parse
    for table in tables:
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 263, in <genexpr>
    return (self._parse_thead_tbody_tfoot(table) for table in tables)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 478, in _parse_thead_tbody_tfoot
    body = self._expand_colspan_rowspan(body_rows, section="body")
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 533, in _expand_colspan_rowspan
    rowspan = int(self._attr_getter(td, "rowspan") or 1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{{vp_count}}}'
>>>
```

How can I address that bug?

Comment: Your error is cause by the "Electoral Result" table. Some cells in that table is spanning multiple columns so I think that's the root cause of your error. However, there are 74 tables on the 2016 page. It's better to narrow down using the `match` or `attrs` params

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I do it in the best way?

Comment: it seems this page may use some JavaScript to add values in place of `{{{vp_count}}}'` but `read_html` can't run JavaScript. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript and use `selenium` on `BeautifulSoup` (or `lxml`) to search elements in HTML - and it will need to write all code to get table, rows, columns, values and put them in `DataFrame`

Comment: `read_html` is useful only if page has classic table(s) crated with `<table>`, `<td>`,`<tr>` without any extra elements or settings. But pages in Wikipedia may create complex tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look into it and try to actually parse the page with Selenium.